# Accessing KeyChain item from OSX Authorization Plugin

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am trying to access Keychain Item after my FileVault login, But I am unable to do this.I have seen that similar kind of issue was in [Error acessing keychain item from OS X authorization plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24561216/error-acessing-keychain-item-from-os-x-authorization-plugin) ,Please help me with this already struggling with this from a week.

Comment: Seems like we're on the same boat with this issue. I even tried to read .p12 file using method `SecPKCS12Import` and it failed from loginWindow authorisation plugin. Let me know if you've find anything. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar situation, it appears that non privileged authorization plugins cannot access 'system' keychain. So I created in advance a new keychain with the items required by the authentication plugin.

```
// blabla is pw for keychain and blabla2 is pw for p12 file.
security create-keychain -p balboa /tmp/my.keychain
security unlock-keychain -p balboa /tmp/my.keychain
sudo -A security import /tpm/mycert.p12 -k /tmp/my.keychain -P blabla2 -A
```

Than, From the authorization plugin, I successfully manage to access the item inside the keychain. In the following pseudo code, I demonstrate how to get a certificate from keychain according to issuer, but any other way for accessing the keychain for reading is also allowed.

```
SecKeychainRef myKeychain = nil;
SecKeychainOpen( "/tmp/my.keychain", &myKeychain);

NSString * keychainPassword = @"blabla";
SecKeychainUnlock(myKeychain, [keychainPassword length], [keychainPassword UTF8String], true);

CFArrayRef keychainToSearchIdentity = CFArrayCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const void **) &myKeychain, 1, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);

const void *keys[] = {kSecMatchSearchList, kSecClass, kSecReturnRef, kSecMatchIssuers};
const void *values[] = { keychainToSearchIdentity, kSecClassIdentity, kCFBooleanTrue, mySearchCriteriaIssuers };


CFDictionaryRef searchItemDict = CFDictionaryCreeate(NULL, keys, values, 4 ,NULL, NULL);

SecItemCopyMatch(searchItemDict, &myIdentity);
```